# Confusion about complete binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I keep seeing it defined as

> A complete binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, except
>   possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left
>   as possible.

But..I have no clue as to what it means by "all nodes are as far left as possible." That's..literally my question. I can't expand on it any further because I have no idea what it means by "all nodes are as far left as possible." Like..as far left as possible compared to what? I don't get it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *as far left as possible* part applies to the **last level**. That is, at the last level, you should start filling nodes from the left.

For example, the following **is a valid complete binary tree** since at the last level, all the nodes are *as far left as possible*

[image]

The following **is not**

[image]

Comment: Ohhh that makes perfect sense actually!